# View the 7 most common words found in the text, but sorting out the words that are common words

Tags: python, compare, text-files, counter, words

really would need some help to solve this or if someone could point me in the right way, thanks!

**View the 7 most common words found in the text, but sorting out the words that are common words. You can find a list of common words in common-words.txt.**

common-words.txt = lots of different words.

first i have found the 7 most common words in the text, this is how my code looks like.

```
    print("The 7 most frequently used words is:")
    print("\n")

    import re
    from collections import Counter

    with open("alice-ch1.txt") as f:
        passage = f.read()

    words = re.findall(r'\w+', passage)

    cap_words = [word.upper() for word in words]

    word_counts = Counter(cap_words).most_common(7)

    print(word_counts)
```

this works and i get the output:

```
[('THE', 93), ('SHE', 80), ('TO', 75), ('IT', 67), ('AND', 65), ('WAS', 53), ('A', 52)]
```

now i want to compare theese two text files, if any of the word in my TEXTFILE.TXT is in COMMON-WORDS.TXT i want it removed from the answer.

i have tried to run it with this code:

```
    dic_no_cw = dict(word_counts)
    with open("common-words.txt", 'r') as cw:
        commonwords = list(cw.read().split())
        for key, value in list(dic_no_cw.items()):
            for line in commonwords:
                if key == line:
                    del dic_no_cw[key]

    dict_copy = dict(dic_no_cw)

    dic_no_cw7 = Counter(dic_no_cw).most_common(7)
    sorted(dic_no_cw7)

    print(dic_no_cw7)
```

and i get the same output:

```
[('THE', 93), ('SHE', 80), ('TO', 75), ('IT', 67), ('AND', 65), ('WAS', 53), ('A', 52)]
```

could really use som help to solve this or some help so i maybe can figure it out by myself.

thanks,

Comment: Please fix your indentation for the first code block

Comment: Quick thought - are the words in COMMON-WORDS all already in upper-case?

Comment: No the words in COMMON-WORDS mixed, some words start with a upper-case some words dont.

Comment: Isn't that a problem then? If you need the comparison to be case-insensitive you'll need to do something like "key.upper() == line.upper()".

Comment: hmm had not thought of this, but they should be so thanks for the tip. im to check this
and see if I get somewhat different results. but think my code is wrong somewhere ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with replacing these lines of your code:

```
for line in commonwords:
    if key == line:
        del dic_no_cw[key]
```

with

```
for line in commonwords:
    if key.strip() == line.upper().strip():
        del dic_no_cw[key]
        break
```

Comment: Tried replacing just as you said,
i get the following message 
"line 434, in commonwords
    del dic_no_cw[key]
KeyError: 'IT'"

Comment: Seems its working.. but the problem is when the word occurs first time the dict key get deleted and so it gives KeyError when same word occurs for second time.

Comment: ahh okay i get it now, but is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: add the "break" statement after deleting dict key.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it, but I think it may be that you're simply checking the value in the dict (which represents the number of times the word appears) instead of checking the key (the actual word itself) when comparing against the words in the commonwords list:

I believe `if value == line:` should read `if key == line:`.

Comment: I tried to replace if "value == line:" with "if key == line:" 
i get the same output as before.